# RuntimeError: No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization

Tags: gpu, streamlit, langchain, llama, llama-index

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/Desktop/investment advisor/app.py", line 39, in <module>
    tokenizer, model = get_tokenizer_model()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/caching/cache_utils.py", line 212, in wrapper
    return cached_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/caching/cache_utils.py", line 241, in __call__
    return self._get_or_create_cached_value(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/caching/cache_utils.py", line 267, in _get_or_create_cached_value
    return self._handle_cache_miss(cache, value_key, func_args, func_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/caching/cache_utils.py", line 321, in _handle_cache_miss
    computed_value = self._info.func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/Desktop/investment advisor/app.py", line 34, in get_tokenizer_model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(name, cache_dir='./model/'
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 566, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/satarupadeb/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 2897, in from_pretrained
    raise RuntimeError("No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.")
RuntimeError: No GPU found. A GPU is needed for quantization.
```

```
#code
@st.cache_resource
def get_tokenizer_model():
    # Create tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(name, cache_dir='./model/', use_auth_token=auth_token)

    # Create model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(name, cache_dir='./model/'
                            , use_auth_token=auth_token, torch_dtype=torch.float16,
                            rope_scaling={"type": "dynamic", "factor": 2}, load_in_8bit=True)

    return tokenizer, model
tokenizer, model = get_tokenizer_model()
```

I was trying top work on a project using llama 2 but  i am stuck with this  quantization error. Would really appreciate some help. I am running this on pycharm.

Comment: What's the output of `nvidia-smi`? What's your system spec. Which llama2 model are you running?